# jQuery Isotope undo Shuffle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

```
    var elems = $grid.isotope('getFilteredItemElements')

    //Shuffle items when [number] or more.
    if (elems.length >= 13)
    {
        ShuffleBlocks();
    }



    function ShuffleBlocks()
    {
        $grid.isotope('shuffle');
    }
```

My Isotope project has a searchbar as a filter,
[Example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wfaGu), when the search results are more than 13 elements in this case I shuffle the Isotope elements.

When I remove my search or return to all / filtered elements, I do not want the items to be shuffled so I need to undo the shuffle before returning to another page.

I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shuffle` is just a sort by random numbers.

Use `$grid.isotope({ sortBy : 'original-order' });` to revert to original order.

See https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/NMjzyQ?editors=1010